# Copying an Array/List without triggering GC

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I am manually copying a smaller array into a larger array:

```
T is constrained to class, new()
```

Why does this trigger the GC? Is the assignment to the new array not by reference? Why are the old elements of the old array still garbage collected? Does the assignment inside the first loop really copy them?

```cs
public void Resize()
{
    T newArray = new T[oldArray.Length * 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < oldArray.Length; i++)
    {
        newArray[i] = oldArray[i];
    }

    for (int i = oldArray.Length; i < newArray.Length; i++)
    {
        // Assign new elements to the new array
    }

    oldArray = newArray;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just the `oldArray` getting garbage collected, and not its contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as you call `new` you create a reference to a new object on the heap. When you assign the reference

```
oldArray = newArray;
```

both references point to the new object. If there are no more references to the object `oldArray` pointed to, it is eligible for garbage collection.

For [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f144e03t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

Releasing Memory. 
The garbage collector's optimizing engine determines the best time to perform a collection based on the allocations being made. When the garbage collector performs a collection, it releases the memory for objects that are no longer being used by the application. It determines which objects are no longer being used by examining the application's roots. Every application has a set of roots. Each root either refers to an object on the managed heap or is set to null. An application's roots include global and static object pointers, local variables and reference object parameters on a thread's stack, and CPU registers. The garbage collector has access to the list of active roots that the just-in-time (JIT) compiler and the runtime maintain. Using this list, it examines an application's roots, and in the process creates a graph that contains all the objects that are reachable from the roots.
Objects that are not in the graph are unreachable from the application's roots. The garbage collector considers unreachable objects garbage and will release the memory allocated for them. During a collection, the garbage collector examines the managed heap, looking for the blocks of address space occupied by unreachable objects. As it discovers each unreachable object, it uses a memory-copying function to compact the reachable objects in memory, freeing up the blocks of address spaces allocated to unreachable objects. Once the memory for the reachable objects has been compacted, the garbage collector makes the necessary pointer corrections so that the application's roots point to the objects in their new locations. It also positions the managed heap's pointer after the last reachable object. Note that memory is compacted only if a collection discovers a significant number of unreachable objects. If all the objects in the managed heap survive a collection, then there is no need for memory compaction.
To improve performance, the runtime allocates memory for large objects in a separate heap. The garbage collector automatically releases the memory for large objects. However, to avoid moving large objects in memory, this memory is not compacted.

Comment: So my question is, what *exactly* gets garbage collected? The elements are all references by the new array. What exactly gets collected from the old array?

Comment: If the only references to your array-items are in your array, the will lose their references along with the array. So all of them...

Comment: But from the code, the old elements should not be garbage collected, since they are referenced by the new array.

Comment: In this particular case, they are not. If there is still a valid reference to an object, it will persist.

Comment: @RecursiveCall: The old array itself gets collected, none of its contents.

Comment: What O. R. Mapper says is true!

Comment: "old array itself gets collected" So it's precisely this part that I want to understand. What *exactly* gets collected there?

Comment: The `array` is an object, allocated using `new`. From `new` you obtain a reference to the `object` on the `heap`. This object requires some memory to exist. When you add an item to the array you create a `new reference` to an `existing object`. When you abandon `oldArray`, the object it referenced has no more active/valid references. So the memory the array occupied can be garbage collected.

Comment: I'm using this mechanism for an ObjectPool, so I guess it's useless. Is there no way to resize an Array/List without "spilling" the references for the Garbage Collector to collect? That is, does the ObjectPool _have_ to be preallocated to a fix size and stay that size?

Comment: In a certain manor, this might support your quest. About how many objects are we talking? 50, 100? If so, this has little to no effect on the runtime behavior. GC has very low priority, so if you are not creating 1000s of objects and release them a few moments after, there is no impact on runtime...

Comment: I Guess this is somewhat of a different topic now, which constitutes a different post.